# WebApi DelegatingHandler not called for preflight CORS requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm trying to implement CORS support for my WebApi controllers, and I'm following the example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx).

My handler looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx
/// </summary>
public class CorsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private const string Origin = "Origin";
    private const string AccessControlRequestMethod = "Access-Control-Request-Method";
    private const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
    private const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    private const string AccessControlAllowMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
    private const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
    private const string AccessControlAllowCredentials = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(Origin);
        var isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;
        if (isCorsRequest)
        {
            if (isPreflightRequest)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

                var accessControlRequestMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();
                if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
                {
                    response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
                }

                var requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
                {
                    response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
                }
                response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowCredentials, "true");

                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                tcs.SetResult(response);
                return response;
            }

            var resp = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
            resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, "*");
            resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowCredentials, "true");
            return resp;
        }
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

In my WebApiConfig class, I'm registering that handler like so:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CorsHandler());
```

And it's getting called for "GET" requests. But it's not getting called for any requests that require preflight approval. The request looks like this:

```
Request OPTIONS /api/campaigns/1002/customerusers/1008 HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Origin  http://app.dev.alanta.com
Access-Control-Request-Method   DELETE
Access-Control-Request-Headers  accept
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
Host    dev.payboard.com
Content-Length  0
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

But as I said, the handler never gets called for the OPTIONS verb.

I thought that there might be some other handler interfering with this somewhere, but I've removed all the likely candidates, and no luck so far.

My other theory is that it's not recognizing that particular route for the OPTIONS verb, and so it's never handing off the request to the WebApi subsystem, and it's getting handled somewhere else. But I'm not entirely clear how to fix that.

Suggestions?

Comment: How about [this approach](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/) to CORS?

Comment: I looked into that, but the main problem I saw (in my brief exploration) is that I need to be able to specify the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" dynamically at runtime, since setting it to "*" prevents you from using the "Access-Control-Allow-Authentication" header. Maybe it has a way to do that, but I didn't spot it.

Comment: Try add this to web.config: `<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV"/>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/></handlers>`

Comment: That was it! Specifically, the OPTIONSVerbHandler. Throw it in an answer, and I'll give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: `return response;` ? IMHO  should be `return tcs.Task`

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You're certainly right that I didn't need the `TaskCompletionSource` in there. Because I'm using the `async` modifier, I can just return the result directly, without calling `tcs.SetResult()`. That was left over from an earlier version which was returning the `Task` directly, i.e., without using the `async` modifier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add to web.config the following:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
</handlers>
```